# return value from awk

Tags: bash, scripts, awk

This is **mybashfile.sh** file

```
.
.
.
awk -f myawkfile.awk mytracefile.tr
.
.
.
```

Now I want to return one parameter from  **myawkfile.awk**  to the current **mybashfile.sh**. Is there any way to return a value from awk to the bash.

For example: this sudo code:

```
parameter = awk -f myawkfile.awk mytracefile.tr
```

In here parameter is the value, which I calulted that on the awk. But now I want to pass that tp the curreny bash.

Comment: I don't get your question. The info you have given is too less.

Comment: @RegisteredUser I did some update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save the output of the `awk` command (`awk -f myawkfile.awk mytracefile.tr`) into a variable so you can use it later in the script, you can do something like this:

```
parameter=`awk -f myawkfile.awk mytracefile.tr`
```

OR

```
parameter=$(awk -f myawkfile.awk mytracefile.tr)
```

This means "save the output of the command to a variable called `parameter`". You can reference that variable later using `$parameter`.